# Transfer SQL Server query to Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, csv

I have this query in SQL Server that needs to be transferred to LINQ:

Table:

```
CaseId    EventId    Activity        Timestamp    Resource   Cost
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1       35654423   register request   2010-12-30    Pete      50
1       35654423   examine thoroughly 2010-12-30    Pete      100
1       35654423   check ticket       2010-12-30    Pete      200
1       35654423   decide             2010-12-30    Pete      200
.           .            .                 .          .         .
.           .            .                 .          .         .
.           .            .                 .          .         .
.           .            .                 .          .         .
And so on...
```

Query:

```
DECLARE @tblCantidades TABLE
(
  iRow     INT,
  Activity VARCHAR(50),
  Cantidad SMALLINT
);

INSERT INTO @tblCantidades (iRow, Activity, Cantidad)
    SELECT 
        TblLog.iRow,
        TblLog.Activity,
        COUNT(1) AS Cantidad
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CaseId ORDER BY CaseId ASC) AS iRow,
             LibroLog.*
         FROM 
             ExampleLog AS LibroLog) AS TblLog
    GROUP BY 
        TblLog.iRow, Activity
    ORDER BY 
        TblLog.iRow, Cantidad DESC;
```

This query returns this:

```
Irow       Activity     Cantidad
---------------------------------
1     register request     6
2     examine casually     3
2     check ticket         2
2     examine thoroughly   1
3     check ticket         4
3     examine casually     1
3     examine thoroughly   1
4     decide               6
5     reinitiate request   2
5     pay compensation     2
5     reject request       2
6     examine thoroughly   1
6     check ticket         1
.            .             .
.            .             .
.            .             .
.            .             .
and so on
```

I have this Linq but I need two variables (startList and final) since the first one will be use to write a `.CSV` and with that I have no problems.

Where "log" is a DataTable that have data from a CSV File with the same Fields as the table in SQL Server and relationship is a Dictionary (string, string) since the program needs to read any Log with same values but different Field names, the dictionary values are the names of the CSV File

```
DataTable tblCantidades = new DataTable();

tblCantidades.Columns.Add("iRow", typeof(int));
tblCantidades.Columns.Add("Activity", typeof(string));
tblCantidades.Columns.Add("Cantidad", typeof(short));

var startList = log.AsEnumerable()
                   .OrderBy(order => order.Field<string>(relationship["Order"]))
                   .GroupBy(group => group.Field<string>(relationship["Case"]))
                   .Select(select => new
                        {
                            everything = select,
                            count = select.Count()
                        })
                   .SelectMany(many => many.everything
                                           .Select(select => select)
                                           .Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, many.count), (records, i) => new
                                                  {
                                                      iRow = i,
                                                      records
                                                  })).ToList();

var final = from table in startList
            group table by new
                     {
                         table.iRow,
                         activity = table.records.Field<string>(relationship["Activity"])
                     } into collection
            select new
                     {
                         iRow = collection.Key.iRow,
                         Activity = collection.Key.activity,
                         Count = collection.Key.activity.Count()
                     } into finalCollection
            orderby new
                     {
                         finalCollection.iRow,
                         finalCollection.Count
                     }
            select finalCollection;
```

But the final variable returns nothing

Comment: I solved it without any help :)